# Is there a way to fix error: No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain. You need to request a codesigning certificate from apple

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I try to debug the app on my Iphone XS, but when I start debugging I receive this message:

```
Error: No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain. You need to request a codesigning certificate from https://developer.apple.com.
```

When I click on the error He send on this part of code:

```
<Target Name="_DetectSigningIdentity" Condition="'$(_CanOutputAppBundle)' == 'true'" DependsOnTargets="_DetectAppManifest;_DetectSdkLocations;_ComputeTargetFrameworkMoniker">
    <DetectSigningIdentity
        SessionId="$(BuildSessionId)"
        Condition="'$(IsMacEnabled)' == 'true'"
        AppBundleName="$(_AppBundleName)"
        AppManifest="$(_AppManifest)"
        Keychain="$(CodesignKeychain)"
        RequireCodeSigning="$(_RequireCodeSigning)"
        RequireProvisioningProfile="$(_RequireProvisioningProfile)"
        SdkIsSimulator="$(_SdkIsSimulator)"
        SdkPlatform="$(_SdkPlatform)"
        ProvisioningProfile="$(CodesignProvision)"
        SigningKey="$(_SpecifiedCodesignKey)"
        DetectedCodeSigningKey="$(_CodeSigningKey)"
        TargetFrameworkMoniker="$(_ComputedTargetFrameworkMoniker)"
        >
```

My target os is 14.2 - the same like my iOS. What can I do to fix this error ?

Comment: Do you have a provisioning profile with your device in it?

Comment: I have apple development account. Is this it ?

Comment: @BenJohnson you need to add your device to your provision profile. Do you know how to create and implement it?

Comment: No .. Can I get some example ?

Comment: See : https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/85290

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/ this is a good resource to get started. You've obviously not done some of the prerequisites to actually deploy stuff to a phone. Start off by signing in to xcode with your development account. You can create a dummy project in xcode and have it set up most of the stuff for you. But read the provisioning docs first.

Comment: Hi, if have a paid apple accout, you could select [Automatic Provisioning for Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?tabs=windows) to check whehter it work. And you also need to have a look at [Device provisioning for Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/) document first.